# Trying to install http_request2 in PHP

Tags: php, apache, http, xampp, httprequest

```
pear install http_request2
```

tried this command,yet giving error like

```
PHP Fatal error:  Array and string offset access syntax with curly braces is no longer supported in C:\Users\harsh\SoftwareC\xampp\php\pear\PEAR\Config.php on line 2095

Fatal error: Array and string offset access syntax with curly braces is no longer supported in C:\Users\harsh\SoftwareC\xampp\php\pear\PEAR\Config.php on line 2095
```

Comment: Which PEAR version are you using?

Comment: @M.Eriksson i checked its `PHP 8.0.2 (cli)`, aint able to check pear version specifically, giving same error `PHP Fatal error:  Array and string offset access syntax with curly braces is no longer supported in C:\Users\harsh\SoftwareC\xampp\php\pear\PEAR\Config.php on line 2095
`

Comment: _"aint able to check pear version specifically"_ - That's what's interesting though, since there's an entry in the changelog for  1.10.10: _"Fix PHP 7.4 deprecation: array/string curly braces access"_

Comment: thanks @M.Eriksson for your help :) ,ill use php-curl.

Comment: I would recommend trying something like [Guzzle](https://packagist.org/packages/guzzlehttp/guzzle) to make it easier.